# KeyDown event foreach textbox in form and detect enter

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2012, keydown, keyevent

I want to add an KeyDown Event to each Textbox in my Form and this is working actually but how can i detect the key then in my event?

This is the Code to create it for each Textbox

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    foreach (Control control in tabControl_1.TabPages[i].Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.TextBoxes_Enter);
        }
    }
}

private void TextBoxes_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((TextBox)sender).KeyDown = ?
}
```

I would know how to do it if i would have one Textbox but how do i detect the Key Enter  foreach one?

This is for one:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to "do foreach one"?

Comment: if the Key is enter i want to use performClick() to activate or use a button. I want to to detect the Key Enter.

Comment: What do you mean? You assigned that handler to every textbox's KeyDown event so it will detect enter key for each textbox. What's wrong in `if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
performClick();
}`?

Comment: its just working for one Textbox if i add the event in the Designer but i want to add it to the event TextBoxes_Enter but how can i do it there. If i write e.KeyCode he does not know keyCode. I want to know how i can detect the key "Enter" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter for how many handlers your `TextBoxes_Enter` method will be assigned - it will behave exactly the same way for each one of them. If it doesn't work, it means you're talking about 2 different methods. I almost missed the fact, that your:

```
private void TextBoxes_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

should be

```
private void TextBoxes_Enter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

BTW, you can assign them just like this:

```
control.KeyDown += TextBoxes_Enter;
```